# How to access a property of one window from the code-behind of another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an application with two windows. One is called `Options`. It has a `string` property `path_to_pure` representing a directory to some file. It can be changed by the user during runtime through an `OpenFileDialog`. In another window `Window2` (which is a separate XAML file), a have a method that takes that property and reads that file into the property of that `Window2`.
Both windows have `INotyfyPropertyChanged` interfaces implemented, if that matters. 
Problem is that I don't know how to access the property `path_to_pure` of the `Options` window from the `Window2` code-behind file. So, what is the most correct WPF way to access it?

**Options Window XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="PVT_Simulator.Options"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PVT_Simulator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Global Options" Height="300" Width="300"
        x:Name="Options_Window">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Options_Window}">
        <TextBlock>Path to pure:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=path_to_pure, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Blue"/>
        <Button Name="btnPurePath" Click="btnPurePath_Click" Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Options Window C#**

```
public partial class Options : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _path_to_pure;
    public string path_to_pure
    {
        get { return _path_to_pure; }
        set
        {
            if (_path_to_pure != value)
            {
                _path_to_pure = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("path_to_pure");
            }
        }
    }

    public Options()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        path_to_pure = "C:/Users/1/Dropbox/PVT_simulator/C# version/Components Lib/General Pure.txt"; // a default value

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    private void btnPurePath_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // creating a file dialog to change file direction
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            path_to_pure = fd.FileName;
        }

    }

 }
```

**Window2 C#**

```
public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // generating pure components names
    string path_to_pure = // I need to acces Options path_to_pure property here!
    string[][] data = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path_to_pure)
                        .Skip(2).Select(l => l.Split('\t')
                        .ToArray())
                        .ToArray();
}
```

I am very new to WPF and MVVM concept, so I would very much appreciate any general advice as well.

Comment: The properties (and the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation) should not be in the window classes, but in a separate class (called the view model). Both windows would then share the view model by setting their DataContext to the same view model class instance.

Comment: @Clemens So, for example, in the cs of  one window I create the ViewModel class with properties and interface, then in this same window xaml bndind DataConext to it; then in another window xaml i do the reference to the namespace containg ViewModel class and also binding window2 datacontext to it? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't matter where exactly you put the VM class, but it's good practice to put it in a separate source file. Then assign the main window's DataContext to an instance of this class (either in XAML or in code behind). Before showing the Options window, assign its DataContext to the same instance.

Comment: @Clemens Could you please tell, if the instance of the VM class should be a Window property then? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's up to you. I'd suggest you get a book or some online tutorials about MVVM.

Comment: @Clemens I'm doing that right now)) One more question - if I have all the properties inside the VM, is that correct that methods of changing these properties also shoul be in the VM? Thank you for you time again))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clemens already mentioned in the comments, you should first make sure to use proper MVVM concepts. So your Options-View (your Options window) and your Window2-View each should have their respective ViewModels (OptionsViewModel and Window2ViewModel...in lack of a better name). 
To help you get started faster I suggest you use a MVVM framework / library. There are a lot of good options out there, personally I like to use [MVVMLight by GalaSoft](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). There you will find many useful classes such as a ViewModelBase-class, which already implements INotifyPropertyChanged or a Messenger, which lets you send Messages between ViewModels easily (for example you can use the Messenger to pass *path_to_pure* between ViewModels).

MVVMLight also offers project templates, which lead you in the "right" direction on how to organize your code between the Model, the ViewModel and the View. Of course there's no absolute right way to do it, but I found it very helpful when learning WPF/MVVM.